Sci-fi story with time-lagged senses
I remember details from a sci-fi book I read years ago, but haven’t been able to identify it by searching on my own. Hopefully someone out there has better recall than I do! The main points I remember:

The main character (or possibly his brother) suffers from a condition where his vision (and possibly some other senses) are time-lagged. He essentially sees what he was looking at a few hours (or maybe even days) ago, which makes it impossible to support himself.
This condition seems to be somewhat common in the book, usually a result of proximity to a warp gate or similar sci-fi travel technology. the length of time-lag increased as it worsened. It might have been called Gate Sickness or something similar.
I’m fuzzy on the plot details, but I think this sickness was a catalyst for the brother of the afflicted to leave their home planet searching for a cure.
I haven’t read many short stories so this was probably a full length novel. I read this in the early 2010’s but I don’t think it was a new release then.
I found a somewhat similar previous question (linked below) but none of the stories in the answers or comments are a match.

Old story about a man with "vision lag" -- he sees what was happening a few minutes ago

Maybe a Philip K. Dick story? I'm sure one of his stories has a major character with such a time displacement, but I can't remember if it was into the past or future. And IIRC, the displacement was a couple of years.

@PM2Ring Are you thinking of The World Jones Made? I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

@user14111 No. In the story I'm thinking of, the time-shift was a liability. It was a short story, not a novel, but it felt like it was possibly set in the same world as another work, because there was a lot of assumed back-story. But I guess a lot of PKD stories are like that. ;) And he often explored themes related to altered consciousness.
